# sort JSON object in ascending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Json response(object)

```
    [{"id":"9","title":"Testing","date":"2014-02-17","time":"40"},
    {"id":"19","title":"11111111","date":"2014-02-24","time":"20"},
    {"id":"33","title":"Testing","date":"2014-02-26","time":"23"},
    {"id":"64","title":"2:00pm","date":"2014-03-18","time":"29"},
    {"id":"65","title":"4:00pm","date":"2014-03-18","time":"33"}]
```

The above is the json object to show the events name and time in event calender.The event name and time are showing correctly in calender.The problem is the event is not showing in ascending order with respect with time.

I need to order the Json response in ascending order.

Is it possible to sort the Json object in the above way.

Comment: have you tried using the Javascript `sort()` method?

Answer (score 2):

The array.sort method should do the trick with a custom function for comparing. eg:

```
function sortObjects(a, b) {
    return (+a.time) - (+b.time);
}

jsonObject.array.sort(sortObjects);
```

I used (+a.time) instead of just a.time because your example shows the time values wrapped in quotes making them strings. The + will convert it to a number.

Comment: Could you please tell me Why we need to write custom function to compare

Comment: because you are comparing the property inside the json object instead of the whole object itself. This will cause the sort to just look at the time property.

Comment: This is what I would do, except that I would probably just put the sortObjects method inline in the sort() call. Depends on if you would need it elsewhere, I suppose.

Comment: Note that the `+`'s are not actually necessary here.  The `-` will force the type coercion.  So, although perhaps it's less explicit, this is also a bit simpler:  `return a.time - b.time;`

Comment: @Danny That's probably appropriate for the real code, but separating it makes the answer easier to read.

Comment: @user2681579: You need to write a custom function in order to tell the sorting algorithm which of the two supplied objects is actually larger than the other.  If you can tell it that for any two objects in your list (positive number means the first is larger; negative means the second one is; zero means they're equivalent) then the sorting system can arrange the whole list.  I'm sure you can see how it might do that.

Comment: @Danny:  I just can't wait for ES6:  `jsonObject.array.sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time);`  Now that's clean!

Comment: @user2681579: Include David's function literally.  Don't try to  introduce this extra line in the function: `<?=$result;?> = json_encode(<?=$event_list;?>);`.

Comment: Exactly what Scott said. Also the .array before the .sort was just to reference the array inside the json object. If it is just an array then you can just use .sort instead of .array.sort.

Comment: @user2681579: I can't really tell you how to see your output.  I think you might need to put a little more work into this on your own.  But you should note that the function `sortObjects` is not what's called directly.  It is simply a callback function supplied to the function which actually should be called, the `sort` function on your array.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged in PHP, so one way to do that:

```
$array = json_decode($json);

foreach($array as $key => $object) {
    $time[$key] = $object->time;
}
array_multisort($time, SORT_ASC, $array);    

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Up then Down, any explanation?

Comment: I removed the php tag from his question. Not sure why you were downvoted though, since OP tagged php but then only addressed javascript-based answers.

Comment: And yet he could rewrite this in 1/2 a second to sort by time instead of start, and he hasn't. Doesn't that interest anybody besides me? Lazy person asking the question who only has enough ambition to copy/paste.

Comment: @skrilled:  Agreed, but I'm bored ;-)

Comment: @user2681579: You either need to decode the actual json and use that array or use the  original `$event_list`.

Comment: With what you posted you're overwritiung `$time`, I used `$object`.  Or because you don't post enough of your data, try: `$time[$key] = $object['time'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own custom comparator function and call sort in your array passing this function

example:

```
  arr.sort(function(a,b){
        var f =a.start.split("/");
        var t =b.start.split("/");
        var x =parseInt(f[2]+f[1]+f[0]);
        var y =parseInt(t[2]+t[1]+t[0]);

        return a - b;
    });
```

You need this custom comparator function, because javascript doesn't knows your object rules. So you need to tell it how to compare your objects.